# Android Call a method from another class

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, call

I know that this Question is repeated but I can't find the answer in the Internet.

I want to call a method from another class.

I have Class1 and Class2.

In Class 2 I have this method:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(){
    //some code
}
```

I want to call the above method from Class1.

Thanks for any answer.

----EDIT----

```
final Button btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpd);
   btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
     public void onClick(View v) {
             Employee updEmple = new Employee();
             updEmple.UpdateEmployee();      
            
    }
    });
```

----LogCat---

```
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198): java.lang.NullPointerException: println    needs a message
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:116)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at   and.net.Employee.UpdateEmployee(Employee.java:77)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at and.net.AndActivity$2.onClick(AndActivity.java:51)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-28 16:30:44.030: E/AndroidRuntime(25198):    at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your UpdateEmployee code, the problem is there you're trying to print something that isn't set

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You should use the following code :

```
Class2 cls2 = new Class2();
cls2.UpdateEmployee();
```

In case you don't want to create a new instance to call the method, you can decalre the method as `static` and then you can just call `Class2.UpdateEmployee()`.

Comment: On what line and when you are trying to use static or the regular?

Comment: I'm using it OnClickButton.

Employee updEmple = new Employee();
updEmple.UpdateEmployee();

Comment: Edit your question and publish the logcat

Comment: It's allmost that simple, yet don't forget in class 2 to add the reference or class 1 won't even compile. public class Class2  extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Class 2() {

    }

Comment: how to get response along with it.

Answer (score 8):

In Class1:

```
Class2 inst = new Class2();
inst.UpdateEmployee();
```

Answer (score 6):

And, if you don't want to instantiate Class2, declare UpdateEmployee as static and call it like this:

```
Class2.UpdateEmployee();
```

However, you'll normally want to do what @parag said.

Answer (score -7):

Add this in MainActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Heightimage.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is not calling for class.This is "starting" to an class.

Comment: I dont care call or stariting it open new class :D