# Passing text output into another method in anther class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a class that performs optical character recognition on images and extract out the text.

For example:

1. ClassA: Performs OCR and sends extracted text to ClassB
2. ClassB: Receive extracted text from ClassA and output the results in 
   EditText

However, now I want to add another process to this system:

1. ClassA: Performs OCR and sends extracted text to ClassC
2. ClassC: Receive extracted text from ClassA and perform a 2nd process to extract out more specific text; then sends to ClassB
3. ClassB: Receive extracted text from ClassC and output the results in 
   EditText

However, I am unable to successfully send an intent from ClassA to ClassC.

**The problem is not how ClassA send the intent, but how ClassC will receive the intent as the receiving method is quite complicated**

Let's say the method in ClassC to do the 2nd process is "EmailValidator()", how do I edit the codes in ClassC so that is would receive the extracted text from ClassA?

Below is the codes in ClassB as of how it **currently receive** the extracted text from ClassA:

```
public class CreateContactActivityOCR1 extends Activity {

    private String recognizedText, textToUse;
    private EditText mEditText1;
    private String mFromLang, mCurrentLang;


    private void setupUI(){

        // Setting up the textbox

        mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailET);
        mEditText1.setText(textToUse);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_createcontact);

        // Getting the path of the image to show
        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        recognizedText = extras.getString("TEXT");
        textToUse = recognizedText;

        // Getting the language used for text recognition
        mFromLang = extras.getString("LANG");
        mCurrentLang = mFromLang;
        //Log.i(TAG, mFromLang);

        setupUI();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        textToUse = mEditText1.getText().toString();
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.usetext);
        setupUI();
        //Log.i(TAG, "onConfigChanged");
    }


}
```

Note that it is able to receive the text from ClassA and display in EditText. What I want to achieve now is to pass this extracted text(known as ***recognizedText*** in the codes) into the method "EmailValidator()" in ClassC.

So how should ClassC receive the extracted text from ClassA, by manipulating the receiving method from ClassB?

Comment: You already receiving text in the above code and that's what you need in the other class to receive text too.

Comment: @Eslam El-Meniawy What i want to know is how do I change the above codes to pass the results to the method "EmailValidator()" within ClassC, rather than displaying it in EditText as shown above.

Comment: Make `ClassC` an inner class of `ClassB` or make that function you want to call public and add `Constructor' to its class and from the other class make object and use it to call the function like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10787205/4983861).