# Calling method from MainActivity class to another class by creating instance android

Tags: java, android, methods, nullpointerexception

I'm looking for a good example, how I can call a method that is declared in MainAcitivity from another class in the same package.

I have a getSMS method in MainAcitivity class, that looks like as following:

```
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        }
public void getSMS(){
            sendSMS("5556", "You're at home.");
    }
```

I'm calling getSMS() method in another class from MainActivity class.

```
public void tSMS(){
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.getSMS();
}
```

Now I'm calling the method in other class using the conditional statement.

```
            if (activity.getType() == 3) {
            tSMS();
                }
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Activities are not supposed to be instantiated manually. If you have code within an Activity you want to call and the Activity is not open, it probably belongs in a helper class.

Comment: If this method have no thing to do with UI of your app. Why not to put it on a utility class?

Comment: You mean, I can call from any other class but can't call from Activity? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787159/android-call-an-method-from-another-class

Answer (score 0):

getSms() and sendSms() shouldn't be defined in your activity. Check some info about structuring your code: https://medium.com/@dmilicic/a-detailed-guide-on-developing-android-apps-using-the-clean-architecture-pattern-d38d71e94029